# Why clone function return -1 when specifing CLONE_THREAD flag?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I write a simple program to demonstrate the thread creation, but the `clone` function return -1 and I don't know what's wrong with my program. Thanks.

The perror says `Invalid argument`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int child_func(void *arg)
{
    sleep(3600);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Allocate stack for child task.
    const int STACK_SIZE = 65536;
    char *stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    int status;
    if (!stack) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (clone(child_func, stack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_THREAD, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("clone");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (wait(&status) == -1) {
        perror("wait");
        exit(1);
    }
    sleep(3600);
    printf("Child exited with status %d. buf = \"%s\"\n", status);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was `errno`? What did your `perror` say?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hi, I have updated the description. The perror says `Invalid argument`.

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)? This: `Since Linux 2.5.35, the flags mask must also include CLONE_SIGHAND if CLONE_THREAD is specified`

Comment: @kaylum This doesn't work.

Comment: What does't work? The manual says you need to do it and your code does not have it. So it may not be the only problem but it is a problem. Unless you are saying you are using are very old kernel.

Comment: "and note that, since Linux 2.6.0, CLONE_SIGHAND also requires CLONE_VM to be included)."

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yes, I have to use `CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_VM` and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Also note `wait` is invalid here, you cannot `wait` for a thread. You need `waitid` with `__WCLONE`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thanks! Save my life. I'm currently struggling for this.

Answer (score 1):

You said you saw `Invalid argument`, which means `EINVAL`. From [`man 2 clone`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html):

> `EINVAL` `CLONE_THREAD` was specified in the *flags* mask, but `CLONE_SIGHAND` was not.  (Since Linux 2.5.35.)

And that's exactly what you're doing.